# Error: Invalid src prop on `next/image`, hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm creating an array of objects where I have an image src property whose name is `coverSrc`, and I'm exporting & importing it into my main component. In my main component, I m using the Material UI CardMedia component to display images. but it gives me the following error:

> Invalid src prop on `next/image`, hostname "res.cloudinary.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

#### `data.js`

```js
export const dataList = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Dim Sums",
    serviceTime: "24-30min",
    deliveryFee: 1.5,
    category: "dish",
    cuisine: "chinese",
    rating: 2,
    price: 4100,
    coverSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/arifscloud/image/upload/v1625119382/image_apxesv.png",
  },
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Dim loups",
    serviceTime: "22-35min",
    deliveryFee: 1.3,
    category: "dish",
    cuisine: "italian",
    rating: 3,
    price: 3100,
    coverSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/arifscloud/image/upload/v1627596941/image_apiop.png",
  },
]
```

#### `ListItem.jsx`

```js
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  Avatar,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import useStyles from "../../../styles/style.js";
import Image from "next/image"


const ListItem = ({
  item: { coverSrc, title, price, deliveryFee, serviceTime, rating },
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.listItemMainDiv}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.ratingAvatar}>
            {rating}
          </Avatar>
        }
        title={title}
      />
      <CardMedia className={classes.media} title="List item" >
          <Image src={coverSrc} layout="fill" alt="image"/>
      </CardMedia>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" gutterBottom>
          Delivery Fee ${deliveryFee}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <div className={classes.cardFooter}>
        <Typography>{serviceTime}</Typography>
        <Typography>{price}</Typography>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

#### `next.config.js`

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
  },
}
```

I think import from array of object's property `coverSrc` there is some problem.

Can anyone help me to figure it out? How can I export coverSrc property from an array of objects?

Comment: I'm doing exactly this and it's still not working.

Comment: You have to add minimumCacheTTL: 1500000!!! Now it works :D

Answer (score 27):

Add the [domain](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#domains) to your `next.config.js` like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true, 
  images: {
    domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
  },
}
```

**Important!**: Make sure you restart your server each time you change the config file.

Comment: You mean the double quotes are the issue here?

Comment: yes this worked for me when I restart the server and its working fine thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Possible Ways to Fix It**

Add the protocol, hostname, port, and pathname to the images.remotePatterns config in next.config.js:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'res.cloudinary.com',
        // You can add these as well
        // port: '',
        // pathname: 'arifscloud/image/upload/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

If you are using an older **version** of **Next.js** prior to **12.3.0**, you can use `images.domains` instead:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  optimizeFonts: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "res.cloudinary.com",
      },
    ],
    minimumCacheTTL: 1500000,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension of `next.config` file to `js`, not `cjs` or `ts`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me at next: 13.1.6

```html
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    images: {
        domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

```html
<Image
  unoptimized <-- Add this
  width={500}
  height={500}
  src={p.thumbnail.data.attributes.url}
  alt={p.name}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, in next.config.js,

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [ "abc.def.org", ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

and then in my Image tag

```
<Image
  unoptimized // <- for image caching, else error
  src={profile.picture}
  alt={profile.picture || "IMG"}
  width={60}
  height={60}
/>
```